# How should I express this

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am writing an email to someone and I want to express my concern that I am unsure if I should do this particularly if this will receive proper attention. I do not know what kind of expression I should use. I know this is a bad description so here is the situation.

I sent my script to a magazine and I was expecting feedback from the responsible editor 8 months ago, so it is seriously delayed (4 times the length they claim it should have taken). I contacted the responsible editor twice, the first time she apologised and said it will not take longer. But the second time (3 months later) I contacted her there is no reply.

I want to write to the chief editor of the magazine and raise this issue because while my script is under review I cannot send it elsewhere. I feel I am wasting my time and I think I deserve some transparency. But of course I have to write it in a polite way rather than just spitting out my anger.

How would you start such a letter/email without giving explicit impression that 'I had enough' and 'here I'm telling on the responsible editor'?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is a language issue, unless you write what you intend to say, and what your concern on that is. Sounds like you are being seriously ignored, though. Unless they owe or commited to giving you a reply, you may be pushing it to demand one. In any case, this might be a question better asked on [***Workplace SE***](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If they have ignored your previous email they can ignore this one. Get on the phone and let someone know you're "fed up with this runaround", and you demand to know if they have rejected your manuscript. Let them know that you will be submitting it elsewhere if they can't give you a definitive answer TODAY. They have no right to hold your article hostage!

Answer (score 1):

**First; remember you must be polite and brief.**

1. You **should do** a list of the actions: example;

a. I sent my script (title, subject, etc.) (email or post) (date)

b. I waited patiently for feedback.  (time)

c. I phoned (date, name) he/she told me... (shortly, example: sorry in two week you'll have and answer.)

d. Second Phone (date)...

e. Third phone (date)...
etc.

That information, you'll write **tidily** in a draft.

**Second:    You should start you mail with:**

Dear Mr/Mrs/Ms (Better if you know the **chief editor's name**)

**I am writing to make a formal complaint against** (Your magazine/service/name of person/etc.)

**My compleint is that** (he/she/yours team/ your editorial) failed to provide me with a satisfactory service when ... (describe your compleint like the list you did.)

This situation has caused me... (example)

In my view, you should ....(example)

I understand that you are required to respond formally to my complaint. I shall follow up
this letter if I do not hear back from you by (give a date, seven days perhaps).   In
the meantime, if you need any further information from me, please (phone me or mail me...etc)

I look forward to hearing from you in the very near future.

Yours sincerely

Your name

**Third:**  When you'll finish; you should read it once.   If you're happy, save the draft and read it again **one or two hours later**. (very important!)

If you'll think it sounds like you want.  Send it!  or make the changes, and read it one hour later.

Remember, All important details must be discribe briefly.

I hope, you can get the answer that you want.